# HTTP POST to OrientDB generates StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: orientdb

When trying to do the following post:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d "{\"@class\":\"Job\",\"@rid\":\"\",\"@type\":\"\",\"@version\":\"\",
\"description\":\"Some arbitrary description.\",\"job_status\":\"Open\",
\"job_type\":\"Developer\",\"title\":\"Foo\"}"
 http://localhost:2480/document/Phtest/
```

I get the following response on the client side:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

And see the following on the OrientDB server side:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB does not accept empty `@type` and `@version`. Remove them or fill them with content. Empty `@rid`is allowed and the POST will return a new RID.